# Products doesn't fit on mobile

Tags: bug, top-bar, design

Products link in nav bar doesn't fit and activates horizontal scrolling in icon area:

> [image]

It needs to responsively disappear, probably (... or just permanently disappear, it's not very useful, everything on it is either also somewhere else or fits in an existing nav menu).

Comment: my understanding is products being displayed in the top menu is considered more important than avoiding a horizontal scroll bar (even though it's entirely useless to the majority of users)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cropped hamburger icon on mobile devices](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288754/cropped-hamburger-icon-on-mobile-devices#comment1241454_288754) - Other similar complaint was closed as *by-design* and explained in that comment - mobile views are being removed, that's how it worked out using the old design; similar trouble for mods who have a diamond on the top-bar, making it too wide for that view on a narrow device.

Comment: @Rob That "cropped" icon is actually just what the Android design was at the time.  It wasn't actually being pushed off the edge, it was intentionally placed there.  This seems different.

Comment: This is still the case and I still have never clicked "Products" and have no reason to do so.